# PHP: What is the best way to get $_POST data?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

I am creating a application that lets you design a meal and add or remove ingredients. However, the issue I am struggling with is $_POST data. The issue I am running into is I need a button for **every** $_POST data form submitted.

For example, I can use view meal button to list the ingredients (as seen in the picture), however since this action refreshes the page, the $_POST[meal] data is no longer there. So when I try to remove a ingredient, it can give me the selected ingredient but not the meals name.

What is the right way to get $_POST data? I am having to basically make a new form and button for every submission. Do I need to use some sort of AJAX so it doesn't necessarily refresh the page and I lose that data? Or do I need to use the $_GET method?

[image]

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['view_meal'])){
        $meal = (string)$_POST['meal_names'];
        $meal_fk_q = "SELECT item
                      FROM meal_ingredients
                      WHERE meal_name='$meal'
                      ORDER BY item";
        $meal_fk_c = $conn->query($meal_fk_q);
        $option_string = "";
        echo "<div class='view_meal_table_wrapper'>";
        while ($row = $meal_fk_c->fetch_assoc()){
             $view_ingredient = $row['item'];
             echo "<table class='view_meal_table'>
                      <tr>
                        <td class='view_meal cell'>$view_ingredient</td>
                      </tr>
                   </table>";
                $option_string .= "<option>" . $view_ingredient . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<form action='createmeal.php' method='post'>
              <select name='remove_ingredients'>
              <option disabled selected value> -- Remove Ingredient -- </option>";
        echo $option_string;
        echo  "</select>
              <input type='submit' name='remove_ingredient' value='Remove Ingredient'>";

    }


    if (isset($_POST['remove_ingredient'])){
        $ingr = $_POST['remove_ingredients'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM meal_ingredients 
                WHERE item='$ingr'";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record deleted successfully";

        } else {
            echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
        }       
    }


?>
```

Comment: if you dont want to refresh the page then AJAX is the way. AJAX is a combination of php and javascript. using it you can communicate with the server and append items to a table using the javascript. then when all items are there, submit the page like a normal form. all the POST data will be on the processing page then

Comment: If you want to maintain information between submissions of a form then you have to make sure that you place that information back into the form each time it is submitted and then refreshed. See `<input type="hidden" name="something" value="somthingelse">`

Comment: If you want to store data between page reloads using PHP then just use `$_SESSION`'s to store `$_POST` data.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the way forwards for you on this one. There are loads more you can add to it to improve, but the basics - using jQuery:

```
var variable-to-send = 42;
$.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php_file_location.php',
    data: {name-in-post: variable-to-send, more: more, andmore: andmore}
    success: function (response) {
        // handle the returned details here
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Then in php you'd do `$data = $_POST ['name-in-post'];`
Typed on mobile so apologies if any errors